# How to create a pandas dataframe vector that has values based on a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, grouping

given the following data:

```py
x1 = 'one'
x2 = 'two'
x3 = 'three'
y1 = 'yes'
y2 = 'no'
n = 3


df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    a = [x1]*n + [x2]*n + [x3]*n,
    b = [
        y1,
        y1,
        y2,
        y2,
        y2,
        y2,
        y2,
        y2,
        y1,
    ]
))
```

which look as:

```
Out[5]:
       a    b
0    one  yes
1    one  yes
2    one   no
3    two   no
4    two   no
5    two   no
6  three   no
7  three   no
8  three  yes
```

I want to know if it's possible to create column `c` as follows:

```
Out[5]:
       a    b   c
0    one  yes   1
1    one  yes   1
2    one   no   1
3    two   no   0
4    two   no   0
5    two   no   0
6  three   no   1
7  three   no   1
8  three  yes   1
```

where `c` is defined as being `1` if for group in `a` the column `b` contains `yes`

I tried the following:

```
group_results = df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x:  'yes' in x.b.to_list() )
group_results = group_results.reset_index()
group_results = group_results.rename(columns = {0 : 'c'})
df = pd.merge(df, group_results, left_on = 'a', 
                  right_on = 'a', 
                  how = 'left').copy()
```

But I feel as though there is a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for test groups with at least one `yes` in `a` column, last convert mask to integers with [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
df['c'] = df['a'].isin(df.loc[df['b'].eq('yes'), 'a']).view('i1')
print(df)
       a    b  c
0    one  yes  1
1    one  yes  1
2    one   no  1
3    two   no  0
4    two   no  0
5    two   no  0
6  three   no  1
7  three   no  1
8  three  yes  1
```

**Detail**:

```
print(df.loc[df['b'].eq('yes'), 'a'])
0      one
1      one
8    three
Name: a, dtype: obje
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use [`Groupby+transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) with [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) after grouping on the conditional series which checks if `df['b']` [`equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) `'yes'` and chain either `astype(int)` or [`view`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html) for integer repr.

```
df['c'] = df['b'].eq('yes').groupby(df['a']).transform('any').view('i1')
print(df)
```

---

```
       a    b  c
0    one  yes  1
1    one  yes  1
2    one   no  1
3    two   no  0
4    two   no  0
5    two   no  0
6  three   no  1
7  three   no  1
8  three  yes  1
```